# Running the contributed command:'extension.node-debug.startSession' failed

Tags: json, visual-studio-code

After updating VSCode, I met this issue when I try to debug on macOS:

> Running the contributed command:'extension.node-debug.startSession'
>   failed.

My **launch.json** is

```
{
  "version": "0.2.0",
  "configurations": [
    {
      "type": "node",
      "request": "launch",
      "name": "Launch Program",
      "program": "${file}",
      "outFiles": [
        "${workspaceRoot}/out/**/*.js"
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

Following [this solution](https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/issues/23965), adding `"protocol": "legacy"`

```
{
  "version": "0.2.0",
  "configurations": [
    {
      "type": "node",
      "request": "launch",
      "name": "Launch Program",
      "program": "${file}",
      "outFiles": [
        "${workspaceRoot}/out/**/*.js"
      ],
      "protocol": "legacy"
    }
  ]
}
```

The error becomes:

> Cannot launch program '/app.ts';
>   setting the 'outFiles' attribute might help.

However, I already have `outFiles`.

Any other solutions? Thanks

Comment: Downgrade to the previous version works for me.